# Speeding up neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an embedded neo4j server with ruby on rails.

These are the configurations:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=240M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=230M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1200M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

wrapper.java.initmemory=1024
wrapper.java.maxmemory=2048
```

There are around `15lakh` movie nodes. The below query is taking around `5secs` to execute.

```
MATCH (movie:Movie) 
WITH movie, toInt(movie.reviews_count) + toInt(movie.ratings_count) AS weight 
RETURN movie, weight as weight 
ORDER BY weight DESC 
SKIP skip_count 
LIMIT 10
```

Here the `skip_count` varies as the user scroll for the results.

and this another query which aims to get the movies from a particular director takes around `9secs`

```
MATCH (movie:Movie) , (director:Director)-[:Directed]->(movie) 
WHERE  director.name =~ '(?i)DIRECTOR_NAME' 
WITH movie, toInt(movie.ratings_count) * toInt(movie.reviews_count) * toInt(movie.rating) AS total_weight
RETURN movie, total_weight 
ORDER BY total_weight DESC, movie.rating DESC  
LIMIT 10
```

How can I reduce the query execution time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding first query:

You might make the weight ordering in the graph explicit by connecting all movie nodes using `:NEXT_WEIGHT` relationship in descending weight order, so the movies build up a linked list.

Your query would look like:

```
 MATCH p=(:Movie {name:'<name of movie with highest weight>'})-[:NEXT_WEIGHT*..1000]-()
 WHERE length(p)>skip_count AND length(p)<skip_count+limit
 WITH p
 ORDER BY length(p)
 WITH last(nodes(p)) as movie
 RETURN movie, toInt(movie.reviews_count) + toInt(movie.ratings_count) AS weight
```

regarding second query:

You should use a index to speed up the director lookup. Unfortunately index lookups are currently only supported for exact lookups. So either make sure the search string is correct in terms of upper/lower case or store a normalized version in another property:

```
MATCH (d:Director) set d.lowerName = LOWER(d.name)
```

Make sure to have a index on label `Director` and property `LowerName`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Director(lowerName)
```

And your query should look like:

```
MATCH (director:Director)-[:Directed]->(movie) 
WHERE director.name = {directorName}
RETURN movie, toInt(movie.ratings_count) * toInt(movie.reviews_count) *         toInt(movie.rating) AS total_weight
ORDER BY total_weight DESC, movie.rating DESC  
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hi Stefan! Thanks for the reply. I think the first query can be structured this way to make it more efficient. MATCH p=(:Movie {name:'<name of the last movie displayed>'})-[:NEXT_WEIGHT*limit]-()  RETURN nodes(p) (As I can keep track of the last movie shown in the user session).

And for the second query: Is there a way to use the `NEXT_WEIGHT` to avoid using `order by`?

Comment: I guess a single director only has <100 movies where he acted as a director. Here it should be fast enough if you make sure finding the director node is done by a index lookup.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work good for this case. But is there any way to execute this using the `NEXT_WEIGHT` relationship. So that it can be used for other similar cases also.

Comment: you could take the first statement, use another `WITH` and a `MATCH` to check if the movie matches the director.